# GitHubにPush出来ません

Tags: git, github

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Ruby on Rails にてサービスを複数人で開発中で、GitHubを使用しております。ローカルで編集したファイルをPUSHしようとしたところ、下記のエラーメッセージが出てしまっています。
解決方法をご教示頂けませんでしょうか？

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
TOMOAKI-no-MacBook-Pro:joinup TOMOAKI$ git push develop features/fukuda/user_view 
fatal: 'develop' does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
and the repository exists.
```

#### 今までのコマンド履歴

①

```
git clone https://github.com/gsrailsteam/joinup.git
```

②

```
TOMOAKI$ git branch features/fukuda/user_view
```

③

```
TOMOAKI$ git checkout features/fukuda/user_view
```

④

```
joinup TOMOAKI$ bundle install
```

##### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

```
TOMOAKI-no-MacBook-Pro:joinup TOMOAKI$ git branch 
  develop

features/fukuda/user_view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git push develop features/fukuda/user_view
```

「develop」というリモートリポジトリに「features/fukuda/user_view」をpushしようとしていますが、

> fatal: 'develop' does not appear to be a git repository

「develop」というリモートリポジトリが見つからないか、正しいリポジトリでないというエラーが出ています。

`git clone` した際、元のリモートリポジトリは通常「origin」と名付けられているので、

```
git push origin features/fukuda/user_view
```

とすれば解決するのではないでしょうか。この時点で「develop」というリモートリポジトリは構成されていないように思います。

Answer (score 0):

「develop」というリモートリポジトリがあるか下記のコマンドで確認してみてください。
`git remote`

表示されたリポジトリ内に「develop」がなければ、
「develop」というリモートリポジトリを新たに追加しなければいけません。